Does a Lunar Cycler make practical sense?
I know that a Mars Cycler has many advantages due to the distance involved, but what about a Lunar Cycler? From what I've seen, the time window seems relatively short, and docking with a cycler consume quite a lot of fuel. Is it really worth it compared to a Low Earth Orbit (LEO) station or a Moon-orbiting one like the Gateway if the goal is sustained exploration of the Moon?

By sustained exploration of the moon, I mean moon landing and/or lunar base.

Frameshift:  If you want to make it easier to go to the moon there's actually another quite surprising approach:  Skyhook.  Anchor your skyhook to the lunar nearside.  The longest cable we can build with currently viable materials is actually easier to reach than low orbit.  Such a cable will never be built for navigation reasons but even one that only drops to a bit above geosynchronous still will save you a lot of fuel.

Potentially
From an economics viewpoint, one of the core advantages of a cycler is that it can be a "purist" spacecraft. Specifically, you reduce the (1) engineering constraints on the design,(2) the per-passenger mass of the system, and (3) you have the option for using more efficient technologies.
For the sake of this argument, I'm going to assume that the cycler has spacecraft it meets at both ends of trip: a rocket brings passengers from the surface to the cycler, the cycler transits, and then it meets with a new lander/descent craft. Additionally, I am only considering architectures which are "sustainable" in the sense that all spacecraft in the system are reusable.
Engineering Constraints
Non-cycler "direct" spacecraft are bound by many engineering design constraints:

Aerodynamics: the spacecraft needs to be able to survive supersonic exposure to Earth's atmosphere and be shaped in a reasonably streamlined manner
Acceleration resistance: Everything in a spacecraft needs to be rated for peak launch reentry loads of 3-4G and high vibration/jerk rates.
Structural rigidity: the spacecraft needs to be able to withstand 1g of force when on Earth (the ISS couldn't do this)
Needs to be able to land: the spacecraft needs to be able to land on the Earth or Moon

A cycler wouldn't have any of these issues. Sure, you still would need to get it into space somehow, but multiple modules that are launched within fairings and then assembled into some sort of ship would be very doable.
If you don't have these specific engineering constraints, you can reduce the...
Per-Passenger Total Mass
Since we don't have these engineering restrictions, we can now start rolling these into mass-savings on the cycler. We don't need a heavy, complex, and expensive heat-shield for reentry, and we can construct the pressure hulls out of thinner and lighter weight materials that we wouldn't want to use on something that people launch and reenter in.
Similarly, since we aren't landing on Earth we don't need parachutes or other landing systems, and since we aren't landing on the Moon we can forego legs or Moon-specific landing systems and we can have very delicate deployed solar panels and radiators that don't need to be "reeled back in" later.
Even other components, like a Launch Escape System or the unfolding ladder for lunar access can be ditched for more savings.
Finally, now that you've saved some mass, you can start to make engineering decisions that would be sub-optimal on a non-cycler:
Efficient technologies
If you don't have high-thrust requirements on your cycler, this opens up the door to all sorts of highly ISP efficient technologies. You can start exploring electric propulsion, which you probably wouldn't do on a regular craft because the mass penalty of bringing an entirely separate engine and fuel tank just for a bit more efficiency is not worth it compared to just bringing a couple more liters of fuel when you already have a second or third-stage engine attached.
Comparison with other approaches
Apollo: The Saturn 5 / Apollo program involved a lot of ditching. After the lunar injection was complete, the third stage was ditched. When the astronauts came back from the surface of the Moon, they left most of the lunar lander there, and once back aboard the command module, they ditched the ascent module too, before finally ditching most of the command module leaving only the reentry capsule on the final stretch. This way, they minimized lugging around mass they didn't need at that moment.
Even disregarding the disposable nature of this system, there are still inefficiencies compared to a launcher-cycler-lander approach. For example, the lunar injection is "harder" than it needs to be because the lander needs to be taken with the astronauts on the way to the moon (compared to already being there) and there really isn't any point in taking the heat shield with them beyond LEO.
Gateway: As I currently understand it, the Gateway architecture essentially involves a launcher/return capsule (Orion) and a lunar lander (HLS) with the Gateway as a stopover point. This is already rather efficient--basically the only inefficiency I see compared to launcher-cyler-lander is that the launcher needs to be quite beefy in terms of Δv so that it can reach the Gateway in the first place. Where the cycler system has a dedicated tailored spacecraft for each section of the journey (reach LEO, get to the Moon, land) the Gateway only has two, where Orion currently needs to pull double-duty of getting to space and then essentially getting to the to the Moon.
In the cycler approach, you could use a lower-powered LEO-only capable vehicle like Crew Dragon or Starliner instead of Orion. Since these don't have the Δv oompf to reach the gateway, you'd dock with the highly efficient electrically-propelled cycler in LEO that then shuttles the crew and cargo to the point where they can dock with and board the lander (or meet Gateway in this case). Here, you wouldn't be lugging around the parts of Orion that aren't needed beyond LEO (basically the reentry system).
Conclusion
Theoretically a ship-cycler-lander architecture can be more efficient than more conventional approaches, because each craft can be precisely tailored to its role and stripped of anything superfluous. The launcher only brings people and cargo to the cycler, the cycler only transits, and the lander only lands.
That said, such a system only makes sense if you are reusing all the components in the system, specifically the cycler many times and have high-enough total system throughput to amortize the initial investment, especially considering that the alternatives probably have a lower up-front cost and less complexity in terms of orbital meetups and timing launches/dockings.

How much delta v would a cycler require per trip to profit from an electric engine?

@asdfex any amount. An electric engine is more efficient than a chemical engine, meaning that it requires less kg of fuel per m/s of velocity gained. If you are asking after which point it makes sense to switch from adding more fuel to a third-stage chemical engine and instead ditch the engine entirely and carry an electric propulsion system instead, then that is an extremely complex engineering decision that can't be made without nailing down a lot of specifics.

@ScienceSnake One of the core assumptions I make is that this system is intended to be sustainable and have every component be reusable. I've added to my answer expanding a bit on the alternative models

This is reminiscent of the old Heinlein model where Earth and the Moon both had stations around them. There were dedicated ground-to-station vehicles on both ends and a dedicated station-to-station vehicle in the middle.

@ScienceSnake I am assuming that the cycler craft is expending most of the dV to match with the launcher/lander using its highly efficient engines
